# Atividade avaliativa horas por minutos

Tags: c, float

> Questão (2): Faça um programa que receba uma hora formada por hora e minutos (um número real), calcule e mostre a hora digitada apenas em minutos. Considere que:
>
> - para quatro e meia (4:30), deve-se digitar 4.30;
> - para quatro e cinquenta (4:50), deve-se digitar 4.50;
> - os minutos vão de 0 até 59

O que tentei fazer:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    float hora, min;


        printf("Insira as horas formatada 0.00: ");
        scanf("%f", &hora);

        min = hora;

            hora = (hora * 60);
            min = (min * 100)%100;
            hora = hora + min;

        printf("%2.0f minutos", hora);



}
```

Mas esse erro sempre aparece:

> C:\Users\Lelre\Desktop\ATIVIDADE AVALIATIVA 2.c|17|error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')|

Pelas pesquisas não posso usar mod com valores `float` mas existe alguma forma de transformar `float` para inteiro para receber o restante da divisão e somar com os minutos?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é isto que deseja.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    float hora;
    printf("Insira as horas formatada 0.00: ");
    scanf("%f", &hora);
    float min = hora;
    hora = (int)hora;
    min = (min - hora) * 100;
    hora = hora * 60 + min;
    printf("%2.0f minutos", hora);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/PfjggG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mxhlgqlb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/CalcMinutes.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @bigown